# Confirming to the user that the message was resent, after it failed on customer support chat

Tags: errors, chat, customer-support, chatbots, conversational-interface

I'm designing a in-app live chat agent support UX. In the situation that a message wasn't sent to the agent, there will be a micro error message below the chat bubble with the resend option.

my question is, after the user resends the message and it is sent successfully, should there be a micro message to confirm that it was sent. Another reason i'm asking this is my current requirement doesn't need to have a micro message for every message that was sent. So wouldn't it be too much information adding this confirmation in this case?

[image]

Comment: Isn't it possible for the app to try and send the chat message again after the failure?

Comment: Amen, just see how Skype behaves when you send a message in offline. As for confirmation of the message did sent, it's an expected behavior, and the single receive time is both useful and clear confirmation. You have no this until a message have sent.